# Which of the following SQL queries finds sids of all the students who apply for CS but not for ME?

Tags: sql

Consider the following relations `Student(Sid,Sname)` and `Apply(Sid,Cname,major)`. Which of the following SQL queries finds sids of all the students who apply for CS but not for ME?

**Option 1:**

```
Select A.sid 
from Apply A1,Apply A2
where A1.sid = A2.sid and A1.major = 'CS' and A2.major <> 'ME'
```

**Option 2:**

```
Select Sid 
from Student
where Sid in (Select sid apply where major = 'CS') and NOT
Sid in (select Sid from Apply where major = 'ME')
```

**I feel both are correct**, But answer is only **Option 2**.

Can you explain **why Option 1 wrong** ?

Comment: Query 1 will return the sid's for anyone who have CS, since for the same row A1.sid = A2.sid and A1.major = 'CS'. The ME condition makes no difference.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Query A return duplicate entries. This query does a self join which creates duplicate rows. To remove this, you have to use a ***group by*** which is not done here.

```
Select A1.sid from Apply A1,Apply A2 where A1.sid = A2.sid and A1.major = 'CS' and A2.major <> 'ME' group by A1.sid
```

Therefore Answer B is the correct Answer